Flask: Render a dynamic template by clicking HTML button
Let's say I have in a view this html code
<html>
stuff...
{% if thisistrue %}
<p> let me see this </p>
{% endif %}
</html>

I'd like to have thisistrue = True only if I press a button from another view. Otherwise I want it to false.
I tried to use dynamic flask routes and jquery like
@app.route('/mainroute/<param/')
def main(param):
if param:
 return render_template(thisistrue = True)
else:
 return render_template(thisistrue = False)

but I failed since it doesn't fit with my subroutes (like mainroutes/somethingelse/

The way your question is currently worded, it's difficult to understand what your actual goal is and what you're failing at. Currently it is clear that you want to display another section somewhere depending on the push of a button. Please describe what, when and how should happen and provide a minimal, reproducible example that shows what your previous solution is and why the error occurs.

@giocanedoli Pl See my answer

@giocanedoli, Once again I've edited my answer and checked for its working. Pl check

Use javascript with onclick event (for button) whose href value leads to new_template.html. The content of the new_template.html will be rendered by the python file.
Edit: The same thing can be done without javascript as well (i.e) using <button href = "/new-template">Submit</button>. But here full page reload will take place and the transition will not be smoother. For the sake of good user experience, the javascript is important.
Edit-2: Since there was an error again, edited now. Since the variable show_data is passed as an argument along with the url(which is similar to the get request), If we declare just show_data= True, It won't work. Instead, it should be show_data = request.args.get('showData', True)`. Now it is working alright.
Please no that there is a difference in spelling and case between 'showData' in javascript and show_data in the python script
HTML with button(index.html)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
</head>
<body>
    
    <button id="new_temp">Submit</button>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("new_temp").addEventListener("click", function() {
            window.location.href = "/new_template?showData=true";
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Python
from flask import Flask as fl, request as rq
from flask import render_template as tmp

app = fl(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index(): return tmp("index.html")

@app.route("/new_template")
def new_template():
    show_data = rq.args.get("showData", True)   
    txt = "This is the new template content!"  
    return tmp("new_template.html", data=txt, show_data=show_data)

if __name__ == '__main__': app.run()

HTML (new_template.html):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    {% if show_data %}
        <h1>{{ data }}</h1>
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>


@giocanedoli Pl see my answer

The problem is that with your solution I always render
{{ data }}
in /new_template and I don't wanna do that.
I'd like to only show {{ data }} when I press the button.
@giocanedoli, Now see my edited answer. This will work exactly how you wanted

I'm sorry for the late response, but this is not working

@giocanedoli, Once again I've edited my answer and checked for its working. Pl check
